# Overwriting specific Line in multiple Files using PowerShell with User Input

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get my PowerShell Script to read the specific line 8 on different `.ctl` files in multiple folders and overwrite it using a premade text and an input made by the user in a textbox.

PowerShell Script:

```
$handler_button3_Click={
if ($textbox1.TextLength -eq 0)
{
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Please Register your Release Number!")
}else{
    #saving the number in releasenr
    $releasenr = $textbox1.Text

    #TODO: Loop which goes into every file on different Folders and replaces
    #line 8 in all .ctl files with following text:     "rel_nr    constant "$releasenr""

    $listBox1.Items.Clear()
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Release Number has been overwritten")
    $listBox1.Items.Add("You can now proceed your Upload")
}
}
```

Is there a way to use a *for loop* to do the overwriting process foreach file that is in a current folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve the files, iterate over it using the [ForEach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet, read the content of the file using [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310), overwrite the specific line and finally write the text back to the file using the [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem 'yourFolder' -Filter '*.ctl' | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_
    $content[7] = 'rel_nr    constant "{0}"' -f $releasenr
    $content | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! If i run the script it reads all files but i get a RuntimeException: Cannot Index into a null Array. Sorry im pretty new to PowerShell.

Comment: Hm, I didn't tested the script but it should work. It sounds like it couldn't read the content of the file. You could add `$_.FullName` to the first line after the foreach-object to print the current file names so you will see which files causes the problem

Comment: As soon as i took out the folder name for Get-ChildItem it worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: you are welcome. Please consider to accept the answer.